# Constructing finite limit from terminal object and pullbacks

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory, limits-colimits, pullback

I'm trying to understand, why in Proposition 3.1 in [Finite Limit in ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite%20limit) (3) implies (1). My intuition tells me to use induction to show that the limit for any diagram having $n$ vertices (objects) (with $n \geq 0$) exists:

Base case: The limit over the empty diagram ($n = 0$) is given by the terminal object.

Now suppose we already now that the limit of a diagram with $n$ vertices exists. We construct the limit of a diagram $D$ with $n + 1$ vertices as follows: We take the limit $L'$ of a sub-diagram $D'$ of $D$ with $n$ vertices. We denote the remaining vertex by $A_{n+1}$ and the terminal object by $T$. Moreover we denote the unique morphism from an object $C$ to $T$ by $t_C$. We now take the pullback $L = L' \times_T A_{n+1}$ of $L' \rightarrow T \leftarrow A_{n+1}$:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
L' \times_T A_{n+1} @>{p_2}>> A_{n+1} \newline
@V{p_1}VV @VV{t_A}V \newline
L' @>{t_{L'}}>> T
\end{CD}

We claim that $L$ is the limit of $D$.

We have that for any morphism $g: L \to A_i$ (with $1 \leq i \leq n$), $g = g' \circ p_1$ for some $g' : L' \to A_i$, since $L'$ is a limit of $D$ (thus uniquely determining $p_1$). Also, since $T$ is the terminal object, $t_{L'} = t_{A_i} \circ g'$. Therefore $t_{L'} \circ p_1 = t_{A_i} \circ g$.
Hence, if there are no morphisms between any of the $A_i$ and $A_{n+1}$, then it follows from the properties of a pullback that $L$ is indeed a limit.

Now my problem comes in: If there is some morphism $h : A_i \to A_{n+1}$, we need $p_2 = h \circ g$. How can we know that this is true? Or can we not know that and I should use a different approach?

Comment: to me your proof seems incorrect for one simple reason: you do not take into account morphisms from and to object $A_{n+1}$. The limit construction you propose is *the same* for every diagram with $n$ elements, which is absurd!

Comment: what i believe you should instead do is to prove facts in the following order: (3)=>(2)=>(1). The first implication is trivial and the second is standard :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have proven the implications in that other direction already. I was just wondering, whether there was a neat and direct way to show $(3) \Rightarrow (1)$. Seems like I was a bit on the wrong track here. If anybody knows a good approach to this, I'd still be very interested in seeing it though.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s look at the situation in $\mathbf{Set}$ for a moment.
Given a (small) index category $I$ and a diagram
$$
 D \colon I \to \mathbf{Set} \,,
$$
its limit $L$ can be constructed as
$$
 L
 =
 \Bigl\{
  (x_i)_i ∈ ∏_{i ∈ I} D(i)
  \;\Big|\;
  \text{$D(u)(x_i) = x_j$ for every morphism $u \colon i \to j$ in $I$}
 \Bigr\} \,.
$$

Let us now remove an object $i^*$ from the category $I$.
That is, let $J$ be the full subcategory of $I$ that is only missing the single object $i^*$.
The diagram $D$ restricts to a diagram
$$
 D' \colon J \to \mathbf{Set} \,,
$$
which admits a limit $L'$.
We have for $L'$ the same kind of explicit description as for $L$.

We find from these explicit description of $L$ and $L'$ that
$$
 L
 ≅
 \left\{
  (x, (y_j)_j) ∈ D(i^*) × L'
  \,\middle|\,
  \begin{array}{l}
   \text{$D(u)(x) = y_j$ for every object $j ∈ J$ and morphism $u \colon i^* \to j$ in $I$,} \\
   \text{$D(v)(y_k) = x$ for every object $k ∈ J$ and morphism $v \colon k \to i^*$ in $I$}
  \end{array}
  \,
 \right\} \,.
 \tag{$\ast$}
$$
We can therefore describe $L$ as a pullback of the following form:
$$
 \begin{CD}
  L
  @> \mathrm{pr}_2 >>
  L'
  \\
  @V \mathrm{pr}_1 VV
  @VVV
  \\
  D(i^*)
  @>>>
  \Biggl( \prod_{\text{$u \colon i^* \to j$ in $I$}} D(j) \Biggr)
  ×
  \Biggl( \prod_{\text{$v \colon k \to i^*$ in $I$}} D(i^*) \Biggr)
 \end{CD}
$$

In your approach, you chose the lower right object in this diagram as the terminal object instead.
This amounts to ignoring all the conditions in $(\ast)$.
You thus end up with the product $D(i^*) × L'$ instead of the limit $L$.
More generally, your recursive construction results in the product $∏_{i ∈ I} D(i)$ instead of the desired limit $L$.

---

I’ve also tried to find a direct way from (3) to (1), but have so far been unsucessful.
(All my ideas require at least the existence of binary products at some point or the other.)